# In Luke 21:22 when did Jesus say the days of vengeance would occur?

Tags: luke, referent-identification, messiah, great-revolt

Jesus described his mission in terms taken directly from Isaiah:

> [Luk 4:19 NKJV] (19) To proclaim the acceptable year of the LORD."
>
> > mGNT Luke 4:19  **κηρύξαι ἐνιαυτὸν κυρίου δεκτόν**
>
> [Isa 61:2 NKJV] (2) To proclaim the acceptable year of the LORD, **And the day of vengeance of our God**; To comfort all who mourn,
>
> > mGNT Isaiah 61:2  **καλέσαι ἐνιαυτὸν κυρίου δεκτὸν** καὶ **ἡμέραν ἀνταποδόσεως** παρακαλέσαι πάντας τοὺς πενθοῦντας

Note that Luke has "days of vengeance" while Isaiah has "days of repayment" which Isaiah has used in two other places:

> [Isa 59:18 KJV] (18) According to their deeds, accordingly he will **repay, fury to his adversaries, recompence to his enemies; to the islands he will repay recompence.**
>
> [Isa 66:6 KJV] (6) A voice of noise from the city [IE: Jerusalem], a voice from the temple, a voice of the LORD that **rendereth recompence** to his enemies.

He announces his mission to proclaim the acceptable day of the Lord in Luke 4:19 but it apparently isn't until chapter 21 of Luke that he announces the days (plural) of vengeance:

> [Luk 21:22 CSB] (22) "because **these are days of vengeance to fulfill all the things that are written**.
>
> > [Luke 21:22 mGNT] (22) ὅτι **ἡμέραι [ἐκδικήσεως](https://www.blueletterbible.org/lang/lexicon/lexicon.cfm?Strongs=G1557&t=KJV)** αὗταί εἰσιν τοῦ πλησθῆναι πάντα τὰ γεγραμμένα

So to what does Jesus refer in Luke 21:22? What vengeance did Jesus refer to and how long would "the days of vengeance" last?

Note: "vengeance" appears here, where God predicted long ago that he would

> [Deu 32:35 CSB] (35) **"Vengeance belongs to me; I will repay.** In time their foot will slip, for their day of disaster is near, and their doom is coming quickly."
>
> > [Deu 32:35 LXX] (35) ἐν ἡμέρᾳ ἐκδικήσεως **ἀνταποδώσω** ἐν καιρῷ ὅταν σφαλῇ ὁ ποὺς αὐτῶν ὅτι ἐγγὺς ἡμέρα ἀπωλείας αὐτῶν καὶ πάρεστιν ἕτοιμα ὑμῗν

Answer (score 2):

Before answering your main question, I want to address whether or not Luke 21:22 and Isa 61:2 are necessarily talking about the same thing, in order to determine how much we should consider Isa 61:2 when interpreting Luke 21:22.

**Is there an allusion to Isa 61:2 in Luke 21:22?**

It appears that in the question, you're asserting that Jesus in Luke 21:22 is alluding to Isa 61:2. I haven't studied this in depth, but at the very least such an assertion would require some amount of evidence, especially since in contrast to Luke 4:19 where there is a clear quotation of the LXX, there is no such lexical similarity between Luke 21:22 and Isa 61:2. (By lexical similarity I mean using the same lexemes, the same words).

Compare the similarity between the NA27 text of Lk 4:18-19 and Rahlf's LXX:

Isa 61:1-2 LXX
Πνεῦμα κυρίου ἐπ᾿ ἐμέ, οὗ εἵνεκεν ἔχρισέν με· εὐαγγελίσασθαι πτωχοῖς ἀπέσταλκέν με, ἰάσασθαι τοὺς συντετριμμένους τῇ καρδίᾳ, κηρύξαι αἰχμαλώτοις ἄφεσιν καὶ τυφλοῖς ἀνάβλεψιν,  καλέσαι ἐνιαυτὸν κυρίου δεκτὸν

Luke 4:18-19
πνεῦμα κυρίου ἐπ᾿ ἐμὲ οὗ εἵνεκεν ἔχρισέν με εὐαγγελίσασθαι πτωχοῖς, ἀπέσταλκέν με, κηρύξαι αἰχμαλώτοις ἄφεσιν καὶ τυφλοῖς ἀνάβλεψιν, ἀποστεῖλαι τεθραυσμένους ἐν ἀφέσει, κηρύξαι ἐνιαυτὸν κυρίου δεκτόν.

There are clear differences but enough lexical similarity (even apart from the fact that Jesus says He's quoting Isaiah) to know He's quoting Isa 61. So not to say that there needs to be 100% lexical similarity for there to be a quote or an allusion, but if there's not at least strong lexical similarity we would want to look for other indicators if we want to argue that there's an allusion or quotation happening (eg, see *Echoes of Scripture in the Letters of Paul* by Hays pg 29ff for a one list of criteria to use when determining if there's an allusion or not).

So then, comparing that to the similarity (or lack thereof) of NA27 Luke 21:22 and Rahlf's LXX Isa 61:2:

Isa 61:2 
...ἡμέραν ἀνταποδόσεως...

Luke 21:22
...ἡμέραι ἐκδικήσεως...

If it were just that one is plural and one is not, maybe there could still be an allusion. But since the word translated "vengeance" is different and even coming from different roots, I'm a bit hesitant. Even more than that, when there are only two words that are similar between two passages, we should be cautious in assuming there is an allusion being made necessarily, unless there are other factors involved (including possibly how rare those two words are, etc). Jesus might also be doing a direct translation/paraphrase of the Hebrew (which happens in other passages where we know there is an allusion), but if so we can only know there is an allusion being made from other factors.

Accordingly, I don't think we should consider a possible allusion to Isaiah 61:2 when interpreting the meaning of Luke 21:22, at least without further evidence. (Although well done keeping your eyes/ears peeled for potential allusions).

**So then what events do Luke 21:22 refer to?**

It seems that as far as timing goes, we have two major indicators of when these things happen:

1. In Luke 21:20, Jerusalem's time has come near when it is surrounded by
   armies
2. This time of desolation is said to endure until the times
   of the Gentiles has been fulfilled (NA27 ἄχρι οὗ πληρωθῶσιν καιροὶ
   ἐθνῶν; 21:25).

We also have to take into account that by Jesus' description, these events will "to fulfill all that is written" (21:22), which seems to indicate a weighty event in my book!

Another factor to consider is that, especially when referring to prophecy but even otherwise, I tend to see if there's an OT backdrop/context that Jesus would share with His original audience, that both of them would understand. Like [Mac's Musings in this answer](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/a/39758/25621), I would say that some of Daniel's prophecies seem to be more in the foreground of Jesus' thought here than Isa 61, especially in light of the fact that Jesus refers to Daniel in the parallel passage in Matthew 24:15 and alludes to the same passage in Daniel in Mark 13:14. Looking at Daniel also gives a potential answer for what the "time**s**" (plural) of the Gentiles could be referring to, since prophecies in Daniel list out a series of times where nations have dominion over Israel (first Babylon, then Persia-Media, then Greece, then Rome). In Daniel, this series of eras (or "times" as the case may be...) then culminates in the end of Jerusalem's desolation, for there comes a rock which destroys these nations, establishing Jerusalem as the capital of the Kingdom of God on earth (cf. Dan 2). This is the direction Jesus continues in as well: from the desolation of Jerusalem under Gentile reign to the end of Gentile reign whereby the kingdom of the Messiah is established; cf. Luke 21:25-28, where Jesus alludes to Dan 7:13 by referring to the "Son of Man coming in a cloud with power and great glory" which culminates in redemption for God's people.

This fits the picture that Jesus describes in Luke as well. There is desolation in Jerusalem until the times of the Gentiles is fulfilled, at which point Jerusalem will no longer be desolate, exiled, or trampled underfoot by the Gentiles.

This fits the timeline presented by a number of other prophets as well, regarding the Day of the LORD. Jerusalem is exiled and under foreign rule until the Messiah returns, ends exile, and establishes his kingdom. This could explain why Jesus would say that this would "fulfill all that is written" (Lk 21:22).

**So then what's the vengeance in 21:22?**

I could see someone arguing it's referring to vengeance on Israel for their covenant unfaithfulness to God, perhaps particularly since they crucified their Messiah. But I could also see it referring to vengeance on both Israel and the nations, particularly since when the OT prophets talk about the Day of the LORD, it is a day of judgment against both Israel (eg Joel 2) and the nations (Obad 15). In other words, since the OT sometimes pictured God's judgment against the sin of the nations and the sin of Israel as two parts of the same coin, perhaps Jesus is doing the same thing here. (Of course, I'm begging the question of all kinds of interpretive issues related to the Day of the LORD...but there's also other examples where Israel and the nations are all pictured being judged together, eg Amos 1-2).

**But how long does it all last?**

Jerusalem had been likewise destroyed and exiled before by Babylon, which is what I'm arguing is the beginning of these "times of the Gentiles". As one of these times of the Gentiles, Jerusalem was under Roman reign, and would destroy Jerusalem in AD 70. These times of the Gentiles will end when the Son of Man returns in the clouds and establish His kingdom. This has still not occurred, and we see how this plays out currently, as Israel still does not have total control over the Temple mount in Jerusalem.

---

Notes/disclaimers:

- Of course I recognize that there is no one single "LXX", since rather there are many Greek translations of the OT, but just using that terminology here for simplicity.
- Again, I am not contributing as someone who has studied this passage in depth but just to add to the conversation.
- I'm coming from a relatively conservative and Premillenial background. Not apologizing for that, but especially for a discussion like prophecy, presuppositions account for quite a bit. :)

Answer (score 0):

Luke 21:20-25 is a sad prophecy about the destruction of Jerusalem by Rome.  In v20 Jesus alludes to the same ideas prophesied in places like Dan 9:27, 11:31, 12:11 (See Matt 24:15, Mark 13:14 where Daniel's prophecies are explicitly referenced in parallel accounts of Jesus sermon in Like 21.)

This means that Jesus' "days of vengeance" (Luke 21:22) is about a (then) future event for vengeance on disobedient Jerusalem about which Jesus wept (Matt 23:37-40).

Note that in Luke 4:18, 19, Jesus NOT quote the next phrase from Isaiah's prophecy in Isa 61:1-3 about the "DAY of vengeance" but as pointed out, discusses the DAYS of vengeance (from Daniel) as part of the prophecy about the destruction of Jerusalem.

Comment: Looking at this verse in context, it appears that the "day of vengeance" refers to the visitation of ~70ad as well:  *[Isa 63:4 KJV] (4) For the day of vengeance is in mine heart, and the year of my redeemed is come.*  Both vengeance and the acceptable year in parallel possibly indicating that they overlap.

Comment: That is possibly true - the year of the Lord's favour, I argue, means the time from Jesus' initiation of the kingdom of God, the preaching of His Gospel, which extends until now.  The Days of God's vengeance sits within that time when God "judged" Jerusalem in AD 70.

Comment: I understand that that is your position but I don't see any argument to that effect. Can you please point out what evidence you cite? Thanks.

Comment: Luke isn't changing the context in Luke 21:20-23, you are; this was likely Luke's way of mentioning the occupation of the anti-Christ(cf. Dan 11:24-26;40-42), which he otherwise doesn't mention explicitly.

Comment: @Ruminator - See my answer to your previous question

Answer (score 0):

There will be great distress in the land and wrath against this people. They will fall by the sword and will be taken as prisoners to all the nations. Jerusalem will be trampled on by the Gentiles until the times of the Gentiles have been fulfilled.The sixth seal and seventh seal, the trumpets and bowls, the Two Witnesses. Revelation 15~20, Jerusalem will be destroyed.The seventh trumpet before the return of the Lord Jesus, the seventh bowl after, and then the New Jerusalem coming down out of heaven from God

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Welcome to the site, James. If you click the Tour link at the bottom of this page you will see how this site differs from most other sites. Your answer refers to some parts in the prophetic book of Revelation, but you need to site chapters and verses. Also, you need to explain why those verses relate to the Luke and Isaiah verses in the question. It may be obvious to you, but you need to present a case, and not just make unsubstantiated claims. Do add a bit more!

Comment: The word of God, that is what I've written. Not unsubstantiated claims. Anne, people can put the words in and the computer gives the chapters and verses

Comment: Hi James, welcome to BH.SE - this is a Q&A site where community members are encouraged to provide detailed answers which explain the sources for their claims. Anne was just trying to help you get started, so please don't take it personally. This Question you've started on was maybe not the best example for you when writing your first Answer, as there are a few other low quality answers here - I've now removed one that was just a one-line answer. For now I'll add a post notice for other users getting started, to indicate that this answer can/should be improved to clearly cite its claims.

Comment: As Anne suggested, it's also worth taking the [Site Tour](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/tour) to learn more about the SE format and how it may be different to other sites you're familiar with.

Comment: Hi Steve, again the word of God, that is what I've written. Not claims. It is from the Holy Bible

Comment: Nobody is denying that you write from the word of God, James. It's just that readers of answers are not expected to do homework, searching out text references. An answer needs to show a logical progression towards a conclusion, not just state a general idea. Hermeneutics requires evidence that will persuade a reader that a good case has been presented. Here's a link to help; notice the graph that backs up the answer. https://hermeneutics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3790/asking-acceptable-questions/3791#3791

Comment: James, these comments are about your formatting. Steve Taylor and I are moderators and politely chose NOT to delete this answer, but it is tempting, just because of formatting. Please quote Bible verses, use block quotes and cite chapter-verse, explain things you state are true. Also, the Two Witnesses appear in Rev 11, your range starts with ch15. So, please do more research. If you don't make changes, I think a mod should delete it, but you would still be welcome to write answers.

Answer (score 0):

#### In Luke 21:22 when did Jesus say the days of vengeance would occur?

The topic "Vengeance" from the *Insight on the Scriptures* has the following:

> ***A fixed time for God’s vengeance.*** The Scriptures indicate that God has a due time for large-scale expressions of his vengeance upon his enemies. The prophet Isaiah was commissioned to proclaim “the day of vengeance on the part of our God.” God’s vengeance was expressed against ancient Babylon, the oppressor of his people, when the armies of Medo-Persia were used to break her power in 539 B.C.E. ([Isa 61:1, 2;](https://wol.jw.org/en/wol/bc/r1/lp-e/1200004551/9/0) [13:1,](https://wol.jw.org/en/wol/bc/r1/lp-e/1200004551/9/1) [6,](https://wol.jw.org/en/wol/bc/r1/lp-e/1200004551/9/2) [9,](https://wol.jw.org/en/wol/bc/r1/lp-e/1200004551/9/3) [17](https://wol.jw.org/en/wol/bc/r1/lp-e/1200004551/9/4)) Jesus Christ, when on earth, quoted part of Isaiah’s prophecy ([61:1, 2](https://wol.jw.org/en/wol/bc/r1/lp-e/1200004551/10/0)) and applied it to himself. ([Lu 4:16-21](https://wol.jw.org/en/wol/bc/r1/lp-e/1200004551/11/0)) Though the record does not say that he quoted the part concerning “the day of vengeance,” in actuality he did proclaim that “day,” which came upon Jerusalem in 70 C.E. Jesus foretold the encampment by armies (of the Romans) around the city, telling his followers to flee from Jerusalem when they saw this, “because these are days for meting out justice [“days of vengeance”], that all the things written may be fulfilled.”​—[Lu 21:20-22](https://wol.jw.org/en/wol/bc/r1/lp-e/1200004551/12/0), *Int;* compare *AT, KJ, Ro, RS.*

So Jesus' quoting Isaiah 61 and its application to Jesus as the Messiah are correct. But Jesus' words from Luke 21 apply to the destruction of Jerusalem.

[All scripture quotations from the [*New World Translation of the Holy Scriptures* (Study Edition)](https://www.jw.org/en/library/bible/study-bible/books/)]

Answer (score 0):

Some points to consider … you have conflated several verses, and the common point is ‘vengeance’. But, you seem to be assuming that the *source* of each/all of these is the same. This may not be necessarily the case ..

First, let’s look at your Q  *When did Jesus says these days of Vengeance would occur*?

Jesus reads the first part of Isaiah’s prophecy… but then …

> **LUKE 19:20** *Then He closed the book, and gave it back to the attendant and sat down. And the eyes of all who were in the synagogue were fixed on Him.* **21** *And He began to say to them, “Today this Scripture is fulfilled in your hearing.”*

So it is suggested that the *second* part of Isaiah’s prophecy, the ‘vengeance’ part, was *not* going to be fulfilled ‘Today’.

‘Today’ - specifically ‘this day’. The period of time we are in. The ‘vengeance’ was clearly *not* for this day, this ‘coming’ - which arguably moves it to Christ’s *next* coming. One reason (of many, but this one is important for this answer) for this deduction is that God is the ‘source’ of this vengeance. The context in Isaiah, the context of the original quote makes this abundantly clear. Isaiah *is* talking about (prophesying about) the ‘end times’ - in each of those selected verses.

But now consider the ‘source’ of vengeance in the other quoted verses. The other ‘Isaiah’ verses clearly reflect the same as Isaiah 61:2 - the end of time. But ….

Luke 21 the ‘vengeance’ is coming via ‘Jerusalem’ being ‘surrounded by armies’ - the Roman armies. I appreciate that some theologians may argue that *despite* this, that it’s really God - but that can *not* be argued exegetically, it can *only* be argued doctrinally. This occurrence in Luke 21, referring to the destruction of the temple in 70AD, was to fulfil prophecy, (DANIEL 9). The ‘source’ of that vengeance came via the ‘people of the Prince’.  (DANIEL 9:26). And Josephus tells us exactly who they were - and the *reason* they did - the ‘source’ of that vengeance was Emperor Titus.

So, trying to ‘link’ those verses via the word ‘vengeance’ is difficult as that ‘vengeance’ is arguably *not* coming from the same source.